# batch file: how can i check if a variable is equal to a number and then goto if yes

Tags: batch-file

im making a battle in a pokemon style game.

i want to check if an opponents pokemon is at 0 health and if yes go to a victory screen and if not goto the next part of the battle

if %wildpkmn-hp% <=0 goto wild-1-victory

if %wildpkmnhp% >=0 goto wildpokemon-battle

this is my code so far

Comment: `If %wildpkmn-hp% LEq 0 GoTo wild-1-victory`, `If %wildpkmnhp% GEq 0 GoTo wildpokemon-battle`. `Equ` (`=`), `Gtr` (`>`), `Lss` (`<`), `LEq` (`<=`), `GEq` (`>=`).

Comment: thank you. this fixed my problem

Comment: Consider reading the help file for the command you are trying to use before you ask a question. The help file for the `IF` command clearly defines the operators you can use to compare strings and integers.